# Angular 4 local storage is not working in IE browser

Tags: angular, local-storage

localStorage get and set methods are working fine but we are unable to clear while logout process, but the same scenario works fine when we open the developer console.

```
logoutFun(){

    localStorage.clear();
    this.route.navigation(['/login']);
}
```

I also tried with localStorage.removeItem(), but it is not working.

Comment: can it be polyfills which causes this?

Comment: not sure though

Comment: Which version of ie are you testing on?

Comment: testing on IE edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved , In IE browser data is storing in cache so now restricted that using the following lines of code in the service

```
 headers.append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache,no-store');
  headers.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
window.localStorage.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, you have a library to save and restore automatically a variable state in your directive using HTML5' Localstorage.

The name of this library: **angular-localstorage4**